# Jstree - only allow to check one node each time in all the Jstree

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, jstree

I have a jstree fill with data and i just want to limit the user to only check one node in all the jstree and when check another uncheck the first and check the other one.

Checkbox property multiple to false not working. My checkbox plugin is configured like this:

```
    'checkbox': {
        'whole_node': false,
        'tie_selection': false,
        'multiple': false,
        'three_state': false,
        'cascade': 'down'
    },
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to limit the user to only check one node in all the jstree and when check another uncheck the first and check the other one.

To achieve your above requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet.

*Hide checkbox(es) of  root nodes*

```
<style>
    .jstree li.jstree-open > a.jstree-anchor > i.jstree-checkbox,
    .jstree li.jstree-closed > a.jstree-anchor > i.jstree-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

*Html code*

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li id="pnode_1">
            ParentNode 1
            <ul>
                <li id="child1_1">ChildNode 1</li>
                <li id="child1_2">ChildNode 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="pnode_2">
            ParentNode 2
            <ul>
                <li id="child2_1">ChildNode 1</li>
                <li id="child2_2">ChildNode 2</li>
                <li id="child2_3">ChildNode 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       
    </ul>
</div>
```

*JS code*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var Tree = $("#tree").jstree({
            'checkbox': {
                'whole_node': false,
                'tie_selection': false,
                'keep_selected_style': false,
                'cascade': 'down'
            },
            "plugins": ["checkbox"]
        });

        //overwrite default behaviour of check_node function

        Tree.on("check_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            var selectedNodes = $("#tree").jstree().get_checked();
            console.log(selectedNodes);

            console.log(data.node.id);

            if (selectedNodes.length > 1) {
                $("#tree").jstree().uncheck_node(selectedNodes[0]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But That's not working for me, any node in all the tree can be selected but only one at each time, for example from your gif for my case ParentNode1 can be selected and when it's checked no more nodes can be checked  and when you check ParentNode2 automatically ParentNode1 has to be unchecked and ParentNode2 checked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have found better solution for this problem

> In order to *hide checkboxes* of *branch nodes* from `jsTree` kindly take `CSS` form **Fei Han** answer

```
<style>
    .jstree li.jstree-open > a.jstree-anchor > i.jstree-checkbox,
    .jstree li.jstree-closed > a.jstree-anchor > i.jstree-checkbox
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

> Use the following code snippet to natively restrict selection of multiple  tree nodes

```
$("#my-tree").jstree({
    "core": {
        "multiple": false
    },
    "plugins": [
        "checkbox",
    ],
    "checkbox":
    {
        "cascade_to_disabled": false,
    },
});
```

All the magic is done with:

```
"core": { "multiple": false }
```

Answer found in `jsTree google group` [conversation 1](https://groups.google.com/g/jstree/c/-4WtiX_bk2o) and [conversation 2](https://groups.google.com/g/jstree/c/KmIJ03iND-U)